# "display: hidden" won't work if not on its own declaration

Tags: javascript, html, css

With this code what happens is if the `formOne.classname = "";` is on its own, it works perfectly, and the form becomes hidden. But why when I have other lines of code around it, it only does it for a split second and then returns to its orginal state?

```
var name = formOne.name.value;
var email =  formOne.email_address.value;   
var e = document.getElementById("typeOfWork");
var q = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var work =  q;

formTwo.className = "form2Vis";



document.getElementById("name1").value= name;
var d = document.forms['formTwo'].elements['name1'].value;// = name;


formOne.className = "form1Hidden";
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is when the user has finished with this part of the email application, they hit next and then the next part becomes visible. Hence why I am making the first form hidden, but I cant get it to work for more than a split second.

Comment: Posting your markup and css or a jsFiddle would definitely help a lot.

Comment: http://codepad.org/IjWR3d4T That is the HTML file http://codepad.org/uikJDEoa and that is the CSS file, which i am using to store the class's that I call

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exactly what you expect but hopefully it will point you in the right direction. I've excluded the form fields in the example because it doesn't work properly in jsFiddle with them.
However, you can use one single form and fadeIn and fadeOut different containers within in.

Here is a simple example of a two page form using jQuery.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sjXPF/3/)

You can use something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
<div id="page1">
<input type="text" name="field1" />
</div>
<div id="page2">
<input type="text" name="field2" />
</div>
</form>
```